# Node.js & ajax / take the data attribute

Tags: ajax, node.js

I send ajax request:

```
var dataString = "{u:" + user + ", p:" + pa + "}"; 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "lg.html",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data){
                        window.location = "http://localhost:8001/ea.html";  
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Now, I have my server in node.js:

```
http.createServer(req).listen(8000);
function req(request, response){}
```

I want to get my form data attribute, so I do the next:

```
request.data;
```

but I see that req.data is undefined. How I can get my data attribute?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `req.body`, there is no `data` "attribute" anywhere?

Comment: @Bergi Express isn't used here. Though, it's a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

With the [`http` module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) alone, you're on your own for reading in and parsing the "*data*."

`request` is an [`IncomingMessage`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) and [Readable Stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_stream), so you do this by binding to its [`'data'`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) and [`'end'`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) events.

```
function req(request, response) {
    var body = [];
    request.setEncoding('utf8');

    request.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body.push(chunk);
    });

    request.on('end', function () {
        var data;

        if (request.url === '/lg.html') {
            data = JSON.parse(body.join(''));

            var user = data.u;

            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a framework like [`express`](https://npmjs.org/package/express) that can simplify this greatly:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/lg.html', function (req, res) {
    var user = req.body.u;

    // ...
});
```

---

Though, if you're passing JSON as `data:`, you'll want to make sure it's [formatted properly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
var dataString = JSON.stringify({ u: user, p: pa });
```

You should also set the `contentType` [to match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/477816).

```
// ...
    data: dataString,
    contentType: 'application/json',
// ...
```

Or, give `jQuery.ajax()` the `Object` and let it URL-encode the `data`.

```
// ...
    data: { u: user, p: pa },
// ...
```